# Scheduling project Reports in sonar

Tags: sonarqube

How can we schedule reports on sonar server for various projects?
Is it possible? If yes then kindly let me know the way to do this.

Your response will be appreciable.
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Sonar has no scheduler built inside. This is the role of a software like Jenkins/Hudson to define the schedules and to trigger Sonar analyses when required.

Comment: ok Thanks Fabrice. Can you please let me know the way to do this?? Is there any option in Jenkins/Hudson for the same??

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by scheduling reports. Running a Sonar analysis? If this is the case then you should look at how Sonar is integrated with CI tools such as Jenkins or Hudson. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Hudson+and+Jenkins+Plugin